# regex - limit word match to the line starting with a specific word

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am having trouble figuring out this problem.. In a list of lines starting with '@....', I want to create an expression that 
first: limit the match to the line starting with '@property'.
second: capture only the words on the matched line to a single group
extra: exclude all words/tags starting with a dash '-t'

I am able to match the line starting with '@property' using either positive look(ahead|behind) however, I am having trouble matching only the words til the end of line.

I am using this to create syntax highlighting for a sublime text package.

[regex editor - link to expression](https://regex101.com/r/uL4dQ2/1)

Comment: Rule is not quite clear. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: You could use the \G construct using the new `regex` module. Using this, it could be done with a single step regex. Otherwise, you would have to do it in with a callback (2 steps). Match the whole line `^@,,,,,,$` then in the replacement callback, match the other items and put into an array, then return the whole line for replacement. Or, without replacement, just match line `^@,,,(.*)` in a loop, then use another regex on capture group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use:

`(^@property|(?!^)\G)(.*? )\K([^-\n]\w+)`

[image: demo]

---

#### Breakdown:

`(^@property|(?!^)\G)`

- `^@property`
  match lines starting with `@property`

OR

- `(?!^)\G`
  start search from the previous successful match

`(.*? )`

match any text until the following capturing group ( *which is preceded by a space* )

`\K([^-\n]\w+)`

- `\K`
  discard all preceding matches from current result
- `([^-\n]\w+)`
  find a word that is not preceded by a dash or newline