# How do you get Regex to match individual words only when the line starts with a specific string?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to have RegEx match all the words in a dialogue that are said by a specific character. Every line is formatted as "[NAME]: [DIALOGUE]", so there's a consistent tag at the start of each line to check with, but I can't work out how to do that. For example, if I was looking Romeo's Dialogue in Romeo and Juliet, it would match each word in "Romeo: I love you Juliet", but wouldn't match anything in "Juliet: I love you Romeo".

The only thing I've thought of as a possible solution is using lookbehind assertions, for which I have `(?<=NAME:[.*])\w+`, but that doesn't return any matches. Through some debugging and looking at the other answers, I've worked out that the issue is with adding the `[.*]`, specifically the square brackets. This lead me to `(?<=^NAME:).*\w+`, which almost worked, but it matched the entire line of dialogue instead of the individual words.

After looking through the review questions when making this post, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311924/regex-to-match-a-word-only-when-the-line-starts-with-a-certain-string), which had the code `\Aframe.*width\s(?<width>\d+)\sheight\s(?<height>\d+)\z`. I tried modifying it to be `\ANAME:.*\w+\s(?<\w+>\d+)\s\z` and then to `\ANAME:.*\w+\s(?\w+\d+)\s\z`, but both returned errors about the second `\w+`, citing "bad escape". I then looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634003/regex-limit-word-match-to-the-line-starting-with-a-specific-word), which had the code `(^@property|(?!^)\G)(.*? )\K([^-\n]\w+)`, but even the base code without any modifcation returned the same "bad escape" error.

Comment: please add the solution you've tried so far along with few samples of your input and the desired output

Comment: @AjeetVerma Was the "for example" in the first paragraph and the code in the second paragraph not sufficient for that?

Comment: For also getting line numbers [try this Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##TVBNb8IwDD2TX2HlQjJYNbRbpYozO@6yAwUEw4VMTVy56RhC/PYuCWUsUiLH9vvQa87@SO61741tiD0wCuHxx0MxUvKtqw36HD6OBDV9YwsW56WTAoYj38ki5bBIYzhTBzdMXBr94f@NPREkkNRC7LGCA/rNiXjfKre1OIUornMRJDjoFXC5hrI2DjeOwvclTiri1ALj0n7WNrXxsdOqgI3O0nOHTQqYPbo20DBmdus/j6piuS7bp0sUv4YiD7fcqWxS7sZzLaeJYxr3FzqhTQU2HwIIDpeDxupGmowolst1eRo/ryaBwGYHpq5RM63vHhh9xy7ChWjYOK8eKcivFJocktB9/ws)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply iterate over the lines and match all words if the line starts with the given character name:

```py
import re

def get_character_words(character_name, dialogue):
  result = []
    
  for line in dialogue.splitlines():
    if line.startswith(character_name):
      result += re.findall(fr'\w+', line[len(character_name) + 2:])
    
  return result
```

Try it:

```py
text = '''
Romeo: Shall I hear more, or shall I speak at this?
Juliet: ’Tis but thy name that is my enemy. Thou art thyself, though not a Montague. What’s Montague? It is nor hand, nor foot, Nor arm, nor face. O, be some other name Belonging to a man. What’s in a name? That which we call a rose
Romeo: Call me but love, and I’ll be new baptized. Henceforth I never will be Romeo.
'''

print(get_character_words('Romeo', text))

'''
[
  'Shall', 'I', 'hear', 'more', 'or', 'shall', 'I', 'speak', 'at', 'this',
  'Call', 'me', 'but', 'love', 'and', 'I', 'll', 'be', 'new', 'baptized',
  'Henceforth', 'I', 'never', 'will', 'be', 'Romeo'
]
'''
```

Comment: It almost works, but it separates out words like "you're" into "you" and "re"

Comment: @Qaos That depends on how you match a "word"; if `you're` should be considered as one word, you can replace `\w` with `\w+(?:'\w+)?`.

Comment: Is there any way to sub the words from the result list back into the original string if the list is modified? I've got the feeling that this project could end up heading in that direction, so I want to ensure I don't get backed into an unsolvable problem.

Comment: I'm afraid that should be posted as a separate question as it could get to a lengthy answer which is probably irrelevant to this one.

Answer (score 2):

A pure regex solution using the third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module:

```py
import regex

def get_character_words(character_name, dialogue):
  return regex.findall(fr'(?<=^{character_name}: .*)\b\w+', dialogue, flags=regex.M)
```

Try it:

```py
text = '''
Romeo: Shall I hear more, or shall I speak at this?
Juliet: ’Tis but thy name that is my enemy. Thou art thyself, though not a Montague. What’s Montague? It is nor hand, nor foot, Nor arm, nor face. O, be some other name Belonging to a man. What’s in a name? That which we call a rose
Romeo: Call me but love, and I’ll be new baptized. Henceforth I never will be Romeo.
'''

print(get_character_words('Juliet', text))

'''
[
  'Tis', 'but', 'thy', 'name', 'that', 'is', 'my', 'enemy',
  'Thou', 'art', 'thyself', 'though', 'not', 'a', 'Montague',
  ...
]
'''
```